# QT multiple files C++ variables

Tags: c++, file, qt, variables

I have a slight problem with my variables in QT. Although it might be more of a structrual problem then an actual QT problem...

I am trying to programm a simple database application in which the user can create a new database and then add / delete and insert entries.

Those files are in my project so far (-the headerfiles):

```
add.cpp 
database.cpp
main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp 

add.ui
mainwindow.ui
```

I want the user to to create or load a database in the mainwindow.cpp.

```
Database* data1 = new Database();
```

my question now is how can I access the object data1 in the add.cpp ?

Sorry, I come from a console c++ - put everything in on file background and haven't read a tutorial yet that answers the question.

Comment: You pass it as a parameter to whatever function is defined in `add`. I'm not sure I understand your question though.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a namespace and make the object globally available in that namespace. I wouldn't recommend this one though, as it is destroying the encapsulation.
Secondly, make your class a `Singleton`, so you keep encapsulation, but can access your object anywhere via `static`-methods.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for `Singleton`.

This would mean to make your constructor(s) `private` and use a `static` method to create an instance of your DataBase-object or access the existing object.

Comment: Thank you both for those quick answers and sorry if the wording wasn't all that clear. I followed Mat's advice and passed the a database pointer as an argument of the add constructor.